# Displaying data from models to index.html in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i want to display the data of models to html template, i've tried every thing but still i'm unable to get what i am look for.

**App name is Home**

Here is the code.

**Home/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class message(models.Model):
    your_message = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.your_message
```

**Home/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import message

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'Home/index.html')
```

In my template index.html i am using this code to display the data from models.

```
  {% for x in message  %}
        <h2>  {{ x.your_message }}  </h2>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `QuerySet` of `message` objects as context to the [**`render(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), thus:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import message

def index(request):
    messages = message.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Home/index.html', {'message': messages})
```

Usually model names are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*. I therefore advise to rename your class to:

```
from django.db import models

class Message(models.Model):
    your_message = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.your_message
```

In the view you then query to that model, and pass it to `messages` to the template, *not* <s>`message`</s>:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import Message

def index(request):
    messages = Message.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Home/index.html', {'messages': messages})
```

Then we render this by iterating over the `messages` variables:

```
{% for message in messages  %}
     <h2>{{ message.your_message }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @BhaweshChaudhary if that solves it for you, marking the answer as accepted will be helpful to others.